# Removing "<<" and ">>" from a file using a sed script

Tags: sed

I have a text file which has a few "<<" and ">>" which I'd like to remove.  I tried the following:

```
sed -e 's/>>//' -e 's/<<//' -i .ORIG file
```

but it does not work.  (I also tried escaping the <'s; although given that I use `\<...\>` all the time in regular expressions, I didn't think it would work.)

What is right command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work for you.

> sed -e 's|[>>]||g' -e 's|[<<]||g' -i.ORIG file

Comment: Could I ask the reason for the [...]?

Comment: [_list of symbols_] Matches any single character in square brackets. I'm using it just to don't keep every time in mind to escape characters.